# React Firebase Cart Add Items Cart Reducer not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

currently working on adding the items to cart using react and redux but the add item does not work

I'm taking the items from my collections page and then passing the key to the product preview page

I'm using react-redux cartReducer the three files are

just can't figure out how to pass the fish products

product page

cart actions

cart reducer

````
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import firebase from '../../firebase/firebase';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addItem } from '../../redux/cart/cart-actions'


class FishPage extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('fishproducts');
          this.unsubscribe = null;
          this.state = {
            fishproducts: []
          };
        }

     componentDidMount() {
          const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('fishproducts').doc(this.props.match.params.id);
          ref.get().then((doc) => {
               if (doc.exists) {
                    this.setState({
                         fishproducts: doc.data(),
                         key: doc.id,
                         isLoading: false
                    });
               } else {
                    console.log("No such document!");
               }
          });

          
     }


     render() {
          
          return (
               <div >
                    <div>
                         <div>
                              <h4><Link to="/">back</Link></h4>
                              <h3>
                                   {this.state.fishproducts.name}
                              </h3>
                         </div>
                         <div >
                              <dl>
                                   <dt>Description:</dt>
                                   <dd>{this.state.fishproducts.description}</dd>
                                   <dt>Discount:</dt>
                                   <dd>{this.state.fishproducts.discount}</dd>
                                   <dt>Size:</dt>
                                   <dd>{this.state.fishproducts.size}</dd>
                                   <dt>Weight:</dt>
                                   <dd>{this.state.fishproducts.weight}</dd>
                                   <dt>Price:</dt>
                                   <dd>{this.state.fishproducts.price}</dd>
                                   <dt>Stock:</dt>
                                   <dd>{this.state.fishproducts.stock}</dd>
                              </dl>
                              <button onClick={() => addItem(this.state.fishproducts)} >ADD TO CART</button>
                         </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
          );
     }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
     addItem: item => dispatch(addItem(item))
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(FishPage);```




this is cart action page 



```import CartActionTypes from './cart-types';

export const toggleCartHidden = () => ({
type:CartActionTypes.TOGGLE_CART_HIDDEN

});

export const addItem = item => ({
    type: CartActionTypes.ADD_ITEM,
    payload: item
})```





this is cart reducer 


```import CartActionTypes from './cart-types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    hidden: true,
    cartItems: []
  };

  export const cartReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case CartActionTypes.TOGGLE_CART_HIDDEN:
        return {
          ...state,
          hidden: !state.hidden
        };
        case CartActionTypes.ADD_ITEM:
          return {
            ...state,
            //cartItems: addItem(state.cartItems, action.payload)
            cartItems: [...state.cartItems,action.payload]
          };
    
        default:
            return state;
    }
  }

  export default cartReducer;```





cant figure out how to pass fishproducts
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So concept of React is that you need to access Firebase with a function. For that you should use a functional component.
React allows Hooks to get access to your state without a constructor so that's all
and then you'll need to use dispatch.

```
  
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase from '../../firebase/firebase';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect , useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import { addItem}  from '../../redux/cart/cart-actions';



const FishPage = (props) => {

        
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        name: '',
        … rest of the values
        isLoading: true,
    })
    const { name, … rest of the values } = state;

    useEffect(() => {
        setState({ isLoading: true });
        const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('fishproducts').doc(props.match.params.id);
        ref.get().then((doc) => {
            setState({
                name: doc.data().name,
                … rest of the values
        
                isLoading: false,
            });
        })
    }, [props.match.params.id])


    const  item = [];
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (
    
        <div >
                    <div>
                        //your body here
                              <button onClick={() => dispatch(addItem(item))} >ADD TO CART</button>
                         </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
    );

}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return{
        addItem: (item) => dispatch(addItem(item))
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(FishPage)
```